# Zadarma API + Python

Tags: json, api, signature

Need help with get json from API

```
import requests
import json
api = 'https://api.zadarma.com'
url = 'https://api.zadarma.com/v1/METHOD'
method = '/v1/info/balance/'
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json',  # Определение типа данных
           'Authorization': 'api_key:secret_key'
           }
response = requests.get(f'{url}+{method}', headers = headers)

print(response.json())
```

Get the next answer:

```
{'status': 'error', 'message': 'Not authorized'}
```

https://zadarma.com/en/support/api
Don't udnerstand how to configurate query correctlly.
Don't find any example in Python. Maybe i do something wrong with signature.

Answer (score 0):

check out their github page. There are authorization functions in there.

https://github.com/zadarma/user-api-py-v1/blob/master/zadarma/api.py